# feeding filenames in azure databrick activity one by one in azure datafactory pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a data factory pipeline where one activity injects names of files (from a container or some other folder) in databricks activity one by one to be processed in the order of incoming. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the source type and the frequency the files are ingested it might be also an option to use spark structured streaming. For streaming data sources also files are supported as a source - Reads files written in a directory as a stream of data. Supported file formats are text, csv, json, orc, parquet (see the docs of the DataStreamReader interface for a more up-to-date list, and supported options for each file format). Note that the files must be atomically placed in the given directory, which in most file systems, can be achieved by file move operations.

```
streamingInputDF = (
  spark
    .readStream           # Similar to Batch just using `readStream` instead of `read`
    .schema(jsonSchema)               
    .json(inputPath)
)
```

If you don' t want to run the notebook permernantly use the trigger once option. With the trigger once option output is written once for available data, without this option output stream would run permanentely:

```
streamingOutputDF \
    .coalesce(1) \
    .writeStream \
    .format("parquet") \
    .partitionBy('ingest_date') \
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointPath) \
    .option("path", targetPath) \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .start()
```

You can use Data Factory to trigger the Databricks notebook without parameter in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Surbhi Tayal and thank you for your inquiry.  By order of incoming I assume you mean the first one sent to databricks should be the first one finished, as opposed to processing in parallel.

To accomplish this, you will need the following:

- a pipeline variable of type array.
- a mechanism to populate the array variable with the file names.  It may be a GetMetadata activity or pipeline parameters or something else.  Add more details to question if you need help with this.
- a Databricks resource and Linked Service

In your pipeline create a ForEach activity.  In the settings mark the 'Sequential' option.  Failure to do so will cause your activities to be sent in parallel, in stead of one-by-on.
In the settings, reference the array variable in the 'Items'.  The expression looks like `@variables('myVariableName')`.
Inside the ForEach activity's activities, place a Databricks type of activity.  The choices are 'Notebook', 'Jar', and 'Python'.  For mine, I used Notebook.  Notebook was easier to set up, because of the UI 'Browse' option.  Set the activity to use the appropriate Linked Service first.  Set the 'Python file' / 'Notebook path' / 'Main class name'.
Expand the 'Parameters' section and add a new parameter.  Give the parameter(s) the same name as in the Databricks script.  The value should be `@string(item())` (may differ if your enumerable is not a simple array of primitives).  This grabs the item from the ForEach activity and ensures it is a string.
Set Libraries if necessary.

When you try to run/debug, be aware that Databricks can take a long time to spin up the cluster.  This increases the pipeline running time.